# Postgresql query construction

Tags: postgresql

I need to write a query to poll a database table only if I ( the application process ) am leader. I plan on implementing leader election via database reservation ( lock a table and update leader record if available every so often ). How can I combine the leader election query with the polling query such that I am guaranteed that the polling query doesn't run if being run by a process that is not leader. This needs to be a db only solution ( for a variety of reasons ).
I'm thinking something like

```
SELECT * 
FROM   outbound_messages 
WHERE  status = 'READY' 
       AND 'JVM1' IN (SELECT jvm_name 
                      FROM   leader 
                      WHERE  leader_status = active)
```

Will this work ?

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: Not yet - reading up on advisory locks :)

Answer (score 0):

This seems overly complicated.

In PostgreSQL you can do that easily with [advisory locks](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/explicit-locking.html#ADVISORY-LOCKS). Choose a `bigint` lock number (I chose 42) and query like this:

```
WITH ok(ok) AS (
   pg_try_advisory_lock(42)
)
SELECT o.*
FROM outbound_messages o
   CROSS JOIN ok
WHERE ok AND o.status = 'READY';
```

Only the first caller will obtain the lock and get a result.

You can release the lock by ending your session or calling

```
SELECT pg_advisory_unlock(42);
```

Comment: I'm guessing the second caller will not block ( hence the *try* ) ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I figured that was what you wanted.